The filter is not returning the different id's its returning everything
So, i have been trying to make a function that deletes reviews and it just isn't working. I narrowed it down, and it seems that the filter is not working correctly, couldn't figure out why. Please check the code and tell me what to do:
//Delete review
exports.deleteReview=catchAsyncErrors(async(req,res,next)=>{
    //Find product by its Id
    const product=await Product.findById(req.query.productId);
    const reviewId=req.query.id.toString()

    if(!product){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Product not Found!",400))
    }
    console.log('Review ID (from query):', reviewId);
    console.log('Existing reviews:', product.reviews);

    //Filter out the reviews by its _id
    const updatedReviews = product.reviews.filter(rev => {
        console.log('Review ID:', rev._id.toString(), '==', reviewId);
        return rev._id.toString() !== reviewId;
    });
    console.log('Updated reviews:', updatedReviews);

    //if the filter didn't work or invalid id

    if (updatedReviews.length === product.reviews.length) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Review not found. Invalid review ID", 400));
    }

    //Calculate the rating and new numofReviews
    let avg=0;
    if (updatedReviews.length > 0) {
        updatedReviews.forEach(rev => {
            avg += rev.rating;
        });
        avg /= updatedReviews.length;
    }

    //Update the product with new reviews,ratings and numOfReviews
    const updatedProduct=await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.query.productId,{
        reviews:updatedReviews,
        ratings:avg,
        numofReviews:updatedReviews.length
    },{
        new:true,
        runValidators:true,
        useFindAndModify:false
    })

    await product.save()

    res.status(200).json({
        success:true,
        updatedProduct
    })

})

//Route
//Delete a review
router.route("/review").delete(isAuthenticatedUser,deleteReview)

Below is the database --
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6686669d001eaace2f3cc103"
  },
  "name": "Product256",
  "description": "MSI Katana",
  "price": 200000,
  "ratings": 4.5,
  "images": [
    {
      "public_id": "Image abcde",
      "url": "SampleImageURI",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6686669d001eaace2f3cc104"
      }
    }
  ],
  "category": "Laptop",
  "stock": 3,
  "numofReviews": 2,
  "user": {
    "$oid": "6680fe296f7960665677f468"
  },
  "reviews": [
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6680fe296f7960665677f468"
      },
      "name": "Someone1",
      "rating": 5,
      "comment": "Excellent!",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "668684131c5010baf9c1fdf3"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "668168d89de2122e5c13c8a9"
      },
      "name": "Someone2",
      "rating": 4,
      "comment": "uhfvkuh!",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6686842f1c5010baf9c1fdfa"
      }
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2024-07-04T09:08:45.192Z"
  },
  "__v": 4
}

As you can see i tried debugging using a lot of console.log and well here is a result--
//Result
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node Backend/server.js`
Server is working on http://localhost:4000
MongoDb connected with server: 127.0.0.1
Review ID (from query): 6686842f1c5010baf9c1fdfa

Existing reviews: [
  {
    user: new ObjectId('6680fe296f7960665677f468'),
    name: 'Someone1',
    rating: 5,
    comment: 'Excellent!',
    _id: new ObjectId('668684131c5010baf9c1fdf3')
  },
  {
    user: new ObjectId('668168d89de2122e5c13c8a9'),
    name: 'Someone2',
    rating: 5,
    comment: 'Remove this!',
    _id: new ObjectId('6686842f1c5010baf9c1fdfa')
  }
]
Review ID: 668684131c5010baf9c1fdf3 == 6686842f1c5010baf9c1fdfa

Review ID: 6686842f1c5010baf9c1fdfa == 6686842f1c5010baf9c1fdfa

Updated reviews: [
  {
    user: new ObjectId('6680fe296f7960665677f468'),
    name: 'Someone1',
    rating: 5,
    comment: 'Excellent!',
    _id: new ObjectId('668684131c5010baf9c1fdf3')
  },
  {
    user: new ObjectId('668168d89de2122e5c13c8a9'),
    name: 'Someone2',
    rating: 5,
    comment: 'Remove this!',
    _id: new ObjectId('6686842f1c5010baf9c1fdfa')
  }
]

The postman is giving the result without removing the review.

does reviewId have any extra whitespace in it by any chance?

No, dont see it

Turns out there was extra whitespace in reviewId used .trim() in filter and it worked. Thanks -VLAZ

The problem lies in how the _id is structured within each review. Specifically, the _id field is nested within an object with the key $oid.
Here is sample code to fix that
const product = {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6686669d001eaace2f3cc103"
  },
  "name": "Product256",
  "description": "MSI Katana",
  "price": 200000,
  "ratings": 4.5,
  "images": [
    {
      "public_id": "Image abcde",
      "url": "SampleImageURI",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6686669d001eaace2f3cc104"
      }
    }
  ],
  "category": "Laptop",
  "stock": 3,
  "numofReviews": 2,
  "user": {
    "$oid": "6680fe296f7960665677f468"
  },
  "reviews": [
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "6680fe296f7960665677f468"
      },
      "name": "Someone1",
      "rating": 5,
      "comment": "Excellent!",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "668684131c5010baf9c1fdf3"
      }
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "$oid": "668168d89de2122e5c13c8a9"
      },
      "name": "Someone2",
      "rating": 4,
      "comment": "uhfvkuh!",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6686842f1c5010baf9c1fdfa"
      }
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2024-07-04T09:08:45.192Z"
  },
  "__v": 4
};

const reviewId = '6686842f1c5010baf9c1fdfa';  // Ensure reviewId is a string
// Here is the fix
const updatedReviews = product.reviews.filter(rev => {
    const reviewOid = rev._id.$oid;  // Access the $oid property
    console.log('Review ID:', reviewOid, '==', reviewId);
    return reviewOid !== reviewId;
});

console.log('Updated Reviews:', updatedReviews);


The log "Review ID: 668684131c5010baf9c1fdf3 == 6686842f1c5010baf9c1fdfa" coming from console.log('Review ID:', rev._id.toString(), '==', reviewId); implies that rev._id.toString() works correctly to produce a string containing just "668684131c5010baf9c1fdf3"

No, even after specifying ,it didn't work

can you make a stackbliz @SoumodeepSamanta033

sure, need some time though, will make it tomorrow
